# CS0120: object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D.AddForce(UnityEngine.Vector2, UnityEngine.ForceMode2D)'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this is my error !

> error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static
>   member `UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D.AddForce(UnityEngine.Vector2,
>   UnityEngine.ForceMode2D)'

pls help me!

```
Rigidbody2D..AddForce(new Vector2 (jumpDirection*PlayerJumpForceHorizontal,PlayerJumpForceVertical));
```

Comment: (I doubt that's your actual code anyway, given that you've got `..` in there...)

Comment: Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2 (jumpDirection*PlayerJumpForceHorizontal,PlayerJumpForceVertical));

Comment: Right - and `AddForce` is presumably an instance method. So read the error message, and all the duplicates of this question (search for the error message and you'll find a lot of them).